# Duda conversión aplicación Python

Tags: python, tkinter, app, pyinstaller

He realizado una pequeña aplicación en Python que tiene una ventana que se abre al pulsar un botón del menú creado con tkinter. Cuando lo ejecuto dentro del entorno de Python no hay problema, se abre sin dificultad, pero una vez hecha la aplicación esta no se abre y se queda una ventana en blanco.

¿Qué es lo que está fallando? os dejo tanto el código como capturas de lo que me sale.

Un millón de gracias por adelantado!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog #libreria que necesito para estas ventanas
from tkinter import ttk #libreria que necesito para estas ventanas
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageDraw #libreria que necesito para imagenes
import numpy as np #libreria que necesito para cosas matemáticas
import time
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import os, sys

#Definición de variables globales
raiz=Tk()


ancho_ventana = 650 #ancho de la ventana
alto_ventana = 220 #alto de la ventana

x_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2 #posición del ancho de la ventana
y_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2 #posición del alto de la ventana

posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana) #determinación de la posición de la pantalla

raiz.geometry(posicion)
raiz.resizable(0,0)

def ventana_insertar_tarea ():
    
    ventana_nuevo_proyecto=Tk()
    ventana_nuevo_proyecto.iconbitmap("foto.ico")
    ventana_nuevo_proyecto.title("Insertar tarea")
    ancho_ventana = 500 #ancho de la ventana
    alto_ventana = 200 #alto de la ventana
    x_ventana = ventana_nuevo_proyecto.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2 #posición del ancho de la ventana
    y_ventana = ventana_nuevo_proyecto.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2 #posición del alto de la ventana
    posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana) #determinación de la posición de la pantalla
    ventana_nuevo_proyecto.geometry(posicion)
    pregunta=Label(ventana_nuevo_proyecto, text="Inserta un nuevo proyecto")
    pregunta.place(x=50,y=75)
    cuadro=Entry(ventana_nuevo_proyecto)
    cuadro.place(x=215,y=75)
    boton=Button(ventana_nuevo_proyecto,text="Actualizar")
    boton.place(x=200,y=120)
    ventana_nuevo_proyecto.mainloop()


elmenu=Menu(raiz)
raiz.config(menu=elmenu)

file_menu = Menu(elmenu,tearoff=0)
elmenu.add_command(label="Abrir Fichero")
elmenu.add_command(label="Nueva tarea",command=ventana_insertar_tarea)

raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: Esto es lo que debería salir]

Esto es lo que debería salir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que sale

Comment: Eso puede deberse a qué ocurre un error al ejecutar el exe. Podrías abrirlo con cmd y mostrar en la pregunta lo que aparece en consola por favor?

Comment: Quizá no está encontrando foto.ico

Comment: literalmente era eso, que tontería más grande. Muchisimas gracias de verdad

Comment: De nada Joanto c: